# Office add-in obfuscation and ribbon controls event handlers

Tags: ms-office, add-in, powerpoint, obfuscation, ribbon

We have an obfuscated PowerPoint add-in. We've excluded from obfuscation the ribbon event handlers from the Ribbon class (the class generated by the Visual Studio add-in wizard).
We now face the following issue: some event handlers are properly called and some are not.
For example, some "button click" events are called, some are not, some callbacks are called and some are not (for example, the loadImage callback is called, because the icons are properly displayed), some getEnabled callbacks are called, some are not and so on.
All event handlers and all callbacks are decorated with the attribute

```
    [Obfuscation(Exclude = true, Feature = "renaming")]
```

Ildasm shows the event handlers and the callbacks are not obfuscated.
Why some event handlers are called and some are not?
Why some callbacks are called and some are not?
Is there a way to ask PowerPoint to create an activity log that will give more information about the custom ribbon created by the add-in (like whether a callback from the ribbon.xml file was found or not)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled "Show add-in user interface errors" as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)? Well, it does not create a log file but displays a message box for each error. So for each callback that is not found you should see a message "The callback function ... was not found". If none is displayed I think you should check what's happening in the callback code as you can assume that the callbacks are called.